# A better way of always dumping Gedit out of Terminal?

Tags: bash

I use terminal *alot*, so it was frustrating to me to deal with gedit's inconsistent behavior between having a window open and when one was not. I ended up searching around, and finding a way of getting around this. I've created this bash script, and aliased it to gedit, and I've slowly been expanding it.

Basically the script does these things:

- Checks to see if arguments exist, if not, it opens gedit with no document
- If arguments *do* exist, it iterates over each and opens them all.

This creates consistent behavior where gedit won't stick in terminal dumping log data.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    /usr/bin/gedit &
else
    for var in "$@"
    do
        /usr/bin/gedit "$var" &
    done
fi
```

My question is if there are any glaring errors here, or if there is a cleaner, faster way of doing this? I'm specifically interested in the loop, as I feel there should be an easier way of passing list data as a single string. The reason I didn't just use $* for that, is when I tried the fact that it's wrapped in quotes caused it to open a single document with all parameters listed as the file name.

I added the quotes for a reason that I should have documented, but I currently do not remember.

Comment: You probably added the quotes to be able to handle space in the pathname.

Comment: I do believe you're right, as that does sound like an issue I would have had to overcome. I'm going to just assume you're right, since trying to test to see if passing a spaced file name using quotes would work incorrectly in this instance would be a pain (and I'm assuming it would)

Comment: The edit info may be a Community Wiki answer instead.  It doesn't belong in the question itself.

Comment: How do I go about adding it there?

Comment: Post it as a new answer at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to make gedit operate silently and in the background, I would create a function (save in ~/.bashrc)

```
gedit() { command gedit "$@" &>/dev/null & }
```

Also, [Accessing bash command line args $@ vs $*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12314451/7552)

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of spacing. gedit test\ file.php test\ file2.php still opens three separate files.

Comment: My mistake, I had forgotten to quote $@

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the answer here due to the linked post. I had originally been using `$*` as I stated above, and was unaware of the differences between `$*` and `$@`. As it turns out, in this instance I needed `$@` because `$*` passes the list of arguments as a single string with all special characters quoted, including any spacing between arguments, while `$@` passes the arguments as a single string, but with only the arguments quoted, so spacing between arguments is treated as spacing for the command.

Given that, I have converted the above script over to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
        /usr/bin/gedit &
else
        /usr/bin/gedit "$@" &
fi
```

Comment: when you have no command line arguments, `"$@"` expands to nothing, so you don't really need the if statement

Comment: That's perfect for my goal of cutting down the code